# repeating Rectangle by clicking mouse in QT QML

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, qt4, qml

It seem that it is not possible to use repeat in mouse onReleased!? how can I do that?I want to apear 4 circle on some Rectangle's edges that already have been defined?

```
onReleased:{
    Repeater {
    id: repeatEdirPattern
    model: editParentPositionList
    delegate: editPatternComponent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MouseArea.onReleased` accepts the definition of a JS function (the SLOT to be called when the `MouseArea.released` SIGNAL is emitted). You can't put arbitrary QML declarative definitions in it.

To do what you need, you have to define your `Repeater` in a `Component` Item, and then when the mouse is released create that component, calling the [Component.createObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-component.html#createObject-method) method.

Another simple way to do it, is to simply hide the 4 circles (setting their opacity to 0) until the mouse is released, then showing them up. Anyway this is not suitable for many cases.